# DataContext in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying the following in my WPF application:

Structure of XAML elements.

```
DataTemplate[Data Type 'A']
    Grid
       Broder
          TextBlock
```

I want to bind the text block's text property to a "string" which is derived from my "Users" class which is referenced in the resource dictionary of the XAML.

1. So in the above structure since the DataTemplate gets the feed from data type 'A'.
2. I want to assign  the datacontext(Users) to the grid and bind the string to the textblock.

Is there a way i can achieve this ,since all my trials which include assigning the datacontext to the Grid or Border or TextBlock doesn't work.

Can any one suggest me or correct me if my approach is wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This markup should suffice:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:A}">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=Users}">
        <Border>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PropertyOnUsers}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Make sure you have the namespace declared at the top of your Xaml. For whatever reason, WPF doesn't always automatically infer the template from the type if you don't use `{x:Type ...}`.

From there it should be straight forward.

If Users is a collection, you will have to drill into the collection to get a specific instance of User.

By the way, if you are using Visual Studio, you can use the Output window to debug binding issues.

Comment: Josh :I edited the above section to make sure that ,I am trying to achieve this.

Comment: @macnique I have readjusted my response. I am now assuming Users is a property on A.

Comment: Users is a property on B actually !

Comment: @Macnique Is B a property on A?

Comment: No. In other words A and B are 2 different classes and Users is a property on B

Comment: @Macnique Are you familiar with MVVM? Can you post code for your ViewModel?